# How to enable sigle div tag and disabling entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to open a div with jquery for login / register for my web application. Im able to display the div by changing the visible property of the div. But at the same time i want to disable entire page. Entire page has to be displayed, but elements like text, buttons or any shouldn't work.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#">Menu1</a><a href="#">Menu2</a><a href="#">Sign Up / Sign In</a><a href="#">About</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id = "dbox" style="visibility:hidden">
        <div id="register"  style="visibility:visible>
            <form .............</from>
        </div>
        <div id="login"  style="visibility:hidden>
            <form .............</from>
        </div>
        <div id="forgotpassword"  style="visibility:hidden>
            <form .............</from>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div id="blog-content">
        <div> Page content </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This is... unclear. Mainly because it's hard to know what result you want: do you want to disable all form inputs? Do you want a lightbox-style effect? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use standard UI element - [JQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) in "modal" regime.

Answer (score 1):

[Create a modal-form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) ,

Or simply

Put your form in jquery modal,

Example for login,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#login" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
        Submit: function(){
          $(this).find('form').submit();
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a div like this, place it after body. Make sure that none of your html elements have z-index greater than 998

```
<div id="fade" style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#ffffff;opacity:.7;z-index:999;display:none;"></div>
```

then above it show your box;

```
<div id="yourBox" style="position:absolute;z-index:1000">

<1-- this is your popup box-->

</div>
```

Call this function on any button click or any event

```
function disable()
{
  var ele = document.getElementById('fade');
 ele.style.display = "block";
 ele.style.display = "yourBox";

}
```